# "I will refuse nothing that you ask of me"

Tags: meaning, sentence

Is the expression "I will refuse nothing that you ask of me" equivalent to saying "I will do everything that you ask of me" in a strict sense?

Thank you,

Comment: @HotLicks That comment would make a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tiny difference.

The first says the speaker will not "refuse", but does not explicitly state that he will "do" what is asked. This gives a tiny bit of wiggle room to not fulfill a request which is "impossible".

But that would be "lawyer's" interpretation, not the "man-on-the-street" one, and the "man-on-the-street" reading would be that the first is the same as the second only more dramatic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. They both indicate that everything is a possible request and that nothing is an impossible request. The first may be a bit more dramatic.